# Spring / Java, good method for remotely interacting with command line Java app on another server?

Tags: java, spring, command-line, ssh, amazon-ec2

I am working on a Spring web application where I have a need to interact with a remotely based command-line java application to run a simple search query on this application and get back the results. I initially had integrated this into my Spring app but my app is, itself, needing a lot of memory (its an app that involves huge amounts of data) and I don't think they can coexist on one server anymore.

I am running everything on Amazon ec2 so the latency between the servers should be really low. I figure I could use a direct SSH connection but am not so sure if this is the best approach. I'd like to keep the command-line app I am interacting with as simple as possible (would rather not make it into a web-service if I don't have to). I'm still fairly new to Java so sorry if this sounds like a basic question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several options other than a web service. Some of them are:

1. [Protocol Buffers](http://code.google.com/apis/protocolbuffers/docs/javatutorial.html)
2. [JMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Message_Service)
3. [Simple socket based client/server Java](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/clientServer.html)
4. [Thrift](http://wiki.apache.org/thrift/)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have or can have spring on both ends -

Exposing service objects and consuming them from a different process becomes extremely trivial using [Spring's remoting support](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/remoting.html#remoting-rmi). (RmiServiceExporter may be most appropriate and least trivial to setup in this case)

It really does away with all the boiler plate code and let's you focus on your business/service logic.

You can write a hello world service and consume it from another Java program in less than twenty minutes. Once you have this "infrastructure" setup, you are free to focus on your actual business logic.

(You absolutely don't have to know rmi to get this working though rmi working knowledge may help if you run into problems. But then, what is SO community for? ;))

Comment: its more where I would be interacting with a command line app and the guy writing that part doesn't know spring or web development at all